# How to use if and endif statment in ternary operator?

Tags: php, conditional-operator

I am trying to write php function but i stuck here how to write if and endif statement in ternary operator? i am using `?:` for if and endif but in my case it is not working. Here is my if and endif statement:

```
<?php if (class_exists('my_class')) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here is how i am trying to achieve this but all the time i am facing parsing error:

```
$mycode = ''. (class_exists('my_class')) ? : '') .'';
$mycode .= ':';
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
**EDITED**
Here is my complete html & php:

```
<form name="myform" method="GET" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>">
<?php if (class_exists('my_class')) : ?>
<input type="hidden" value="product" name="post_type">
<?php endif; ?>
<input type="text"  name="s" class="searchbox" maxlength="128" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>">
```

and here is how i am converting it:

```
<?php
$mycode = '<div class="main_form"><form name="myform" method="GET" action="'.esc_url(home_url('/')).'">';
$mycode .= ''. (class_exists('my_class')) ? : '') .'';
$mycode .='<input type="hidden" value="product" name="post_type">';
$mycode .= ':';
?>
```

Comment: Unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve. `?:` is not synonymous with `if/endif`, and a ternary operator can't be broken up across PHP start/end tags. You may find [Shorthand comparisons in PHP](https://stitcher.io/blog/shorthand-comparisons-in-php) a useful read. Meanwhile, please clarify what your desired outcome is.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact error message you get. Also read it carefully, and try to think about what it might be telling you.

Comment: A ternary operator has three parts as its name suggests - a condition, a result for true and a result for false.  I can't see that your code anywhere has a requirement for those 3 parts, only for two (if a condition is met then echo an extra HTML input element). Is there some reason you think a ternary operator is required or that you'd like to use one?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like
$mycode = class_exists('my_class') ? 'something' : 'something else';